# Quando usamos async não precisa usar callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-aws, assincronismo, callback

Tenho a seguinte função em nodeJs v10.6:

```
#func-1
module.exports.funcOne = (event, context, callback) => { 
  callback(null, { message: 'funcOne', event });
};

#func-2
module.exports.funcTwo = async (event, context) => { 
  console.log("value1 = " + event.key1);
  console.log("value2 = " + event.key2);  
  return 'some success message';
};
```

Quando eu rodo o comando no terminal: `sls invoke local --function funcOne` tenho a resposta:

```
{
    "message": "funcOne",
    "event": ""
}
```

E quando eu rodo o comando `sls invoke local --function funcTwo` tenho a resposta:

```
value1 = undefined
value2 = undefined
```

Não consigo ver `some success message`;

Estou seguindo a [documentação do AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-handler.html) para lambda functions e NodeJs tentando entender as funções assincronas com callbacks.

Alguém poderia explicar pq não vejo a string no segundo exemplo?

Comment: Então, eu não sei te dizer com 100% de certeza se é isso, mas, pela experiência que tenho com JS, quando você usa async, pra você ter o resultado da funçao que retorna um async, você precisa usar o await, então, se você fosse chamar essa função normalmente, você usaria let x = await funcTwo(), por exemplo, e x teria o retorno dela. Não sei se é esse o caso, mas..